# Windows command: show command's file path

Tags: windows, command, filepath, windows-console

I want to find the file path of any command, for example:

```
C:\Users\trungdq3>show-command-path notepad
C:\Windows\notepad.exe

C:\Users\trungdq3>show-command-path java
C:\Java\jdk1.6\bin\java.exe
```

Of course `show-command-path` is not a valid command, is there any command like that available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `where` is the command you are looking for.
***MSDN:*** http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753148.aspx